# Page transition duration in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

How can I choose a specific transition duration for a **Cupertino Page Route** navigation ?

Like when I navigate from one page to another I need the animation duration to take longer to show the flip effect.

Comment: Try to post the code you have tried until now. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: That's the problem, I'm still a beginner in flutter, so I didn't write any code for what  I'm asking about, all I wrote so far is 
`Navigator.push(context, ScaleRoute(page: Immatry()));`

Comment: Please see the address of the CSDN to answer the question
https://blog.csdn.net/u013491829/article/details/108905233
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyPUG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should have something along the lines of `transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1)`. If not that exact property, there will be something else related to `duration`.

Comment: Thanks but where should I put the line exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

you need something like

```
class MainPageState extends State<MainPage>{

startTime() async {
var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 3);
return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
}

void navigationPage() {
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("Route");
}
}
```